# Multiply Django Apache servers

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I currently have one server with an Apache-Django app running on it along with postgresDB.

1. I would like to add another server with the Apache-Django app that is connected to the same postgresDB instance. I would like both the apps to be synchronized and running.
2. Both of the apps would run, but only one will be in the requested, active passive state - should I use a proxy server for this?

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @Ariel Livshits if you have under control all the underlying issues of being in this architecture like handling static files or sessions (to mention a few), you could accomplish this using HAProxy as load balancer. It's very simple actually:

> **Automatic failover without failback**
>
> Sample server configuration:
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  |  HAProxy  |
>  -------------
>   |         `
>   |active    ` backup
>   |           `
> ------       ------
> | s1 |       | s2 |
> ```
>
> The configuration below makes HAProxy to use s1 when available, otherwise fail over to s2 if available.
>   When a failover has occured, no failback will be processed automatically, thanks to the stick table:
>
> ```
> peers LB
>  peer LB1 10.0.0.98:1234
>  peer LB2 10.0.0.99:1234
>
> defaults
>  mode http
>  option http-server-close
>  timeout client 20s
>  timeout server 20s
>  timeout connect 4s
>
> frontend ft_app
>  bind 10.0.0.100:80 name app
>  default_backend bk_app
>
> backend bk_app
>  stick-table type ip size 1 nopurge peers LB
>  stick on dst
>  server s1 10.0.0.1:80 check
>  server s2 10.0.0.2:80 check backup
> ```

[Source](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/01/17/emulating-activepassing-application-clustering-with-haproxy/)

Comment: It sounds like what I was thinking , thank you I will check it